# How to embed or customize office type ribbon tools in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, ribbon-control

I am planning to embed ribbon type tool (like in Outlook) in my **PhoneTextBox** which would provide functionalities like Attachments, draw table etc. So any API's or Namespaces available for the same or do we have to customize and make our own custom ribbon controls and embed inside the textbox control.
Any code snippets on this would be great.
Thanks In Advance!!..

Comment: Anyone any help or ideas on the same??..

Answer (score 0):

1. There are no ribbon controls available out-of-the-box for Windows Phone.
2. You should not use/implement ribbon controls on Windows Phone. Mainly because the OS was designed to have a user interaction mechanism that does not fit the ribbon model. You have very limited screen real estate and don't want to fill it with unnecessary controls.
3. Why would you want to embed a ribbon in a `TextBox`?

Comment: Ok..Not embed may be I got it wrong, but use the ribbon control for the textbox text. Actually I want to use this text as message body which can then be sent via emailcomposetask. So if the user wants to put some attachments like images etc, or change fonts or add table etc, hence thought of a ribbon control.

Comment: You can use standard buttons for that, like other applications on Windows Phone. Keep the user experience consistent with the OS.